# Reference for automorphisms of field extensions with non-zero transcendence degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, field-theory, book-recommendation, transcendence-degree

I'm looking for a book/reference that discusses automorphisms of field extensions which are not purely algebraic. Dummit and Foote only has a couple pages about this, and I wanted to learn more. I apologize in advance if this is not the correct place to ask.

Comment: This is difficult in full generality. In transcendence degree $1$ it's equivalent to asking about automorphisms of algebraic curves, or Riemann surfaces in the complex case. There's a lot to say here, but see, for example, Hurwitz's automorphism theorem.